# java set object field equal another field upon instantation

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am mapping a json list to java list of objects.  The class I am mapping to has an extra time field (local time).

In the incoming json, the timestamp field appears as 1510549200000 (UTC time stamp) for example.  This example corresponds to a date:  Monday, November 13, 2017 12:00:00 AM GMT-05:00 in local time

upon mapping to the class, I need to assign a local time based on the incoming UTC value.

The mapping is done as follows:

```
List<myClass> items = objectMapper.readValue(
       jsn_a.toString(), new TypeReference<List<myClass>>() {});
```

and in the Class constructor I have is:

```
public myClass() {
    this.localTime= myUTCTime; 
}
```

But when I look at the resulting list of objects, I see that localTime is still set to null.

I can see why this is happening (constructor is called first); but how do I go about assigning the utc timestamp to the localTime field during the object creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Java-JSON mapping libraries invoke the no arg constructor to unserialize a JSON object into a Java Object.
According to the libraries you use you could use a way to set the fields from the arg constructor.
Or more simply invoke the setter on the field after default unserialization :

```
Foo foo = ... // unserialize from json
foo.setLocalTime(myUTCTime);
```

Comment: Thanks ... I sort did same in my setter.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind,  I figured this out as soon as I posted the question.   I assigned the local time value in the utc field setter.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  With that being the case, I urge you either to edit this into a full answer to the question, or else to delete the question.